# Ошибка PHP "unexpected T_VARIABLE"

Tags: php

Ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   D:\Work\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\laba\game.php on line 7

Что не так с этим кодом?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['num'])) {
    $number = (int) $_POST['num'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['answer'])
    $_SESSION['answer'] = mt_rand(1, 10);
if(!isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
    $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1;

if ($number > $_SESSION['answer']){
    echo 'Слишком большое.';
    $_SESSION['attempts']++;
}
elseif ($number < $_SESSION['answer']){
    echo 'Слишком маленькое.';
    $_SESSION['attempts']++;
}
else {
    echo 'Ура! Вы отгадали после <b>', $_SESSION['attempts'], '</b> попыток!';
    session_destroy();
}
}
?>
```

Что-то мне подсказывает что в нём несколько проблемных мест

Comment: Скобки раставьте мож увидите, и сообщение переведите... И отступы тоже...

Comment: Какие скобки? Сообщения перевёл

Comment: Всё, заработало, одной скобки не хватало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да ну его напишу ответ как надо писать што бы не ошибаться в элементарном:

1. Форматирование кода при форматирование применяется 4-ре пробела в контексте оператора к примеру ваш код будет выглядить так
2. операторы `if` и `else` должны содержать управляющие конструкции `{}`

результат:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['num'])) {

    $number = (int) $_POST['num'];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['answer']) {
        $_SESSION['answer'] = mt_rand(1, 10);
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['attempts'])) {
        $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1;
    }

    if ($number > $_SESSION['answer']) {
        echo 'Too big.';
        $_SESSION['attempts']++;
    } elseif ($number < $_SESSION['answer']) {
        echo 'Too small.';
        $_SESSION['attempts']++;
    } else {
        echo 'Yeah! You answered after <b>', $_SESSION['attempts'], '</b> attempts!';
        session_destroy();
    }
}  
?>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in D:\Work\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\laba\game.php on line 8`

Comment: @Naumov, ваше форматирование на 4ре пробела не тянет :Р

Comment: @Alexander, у вас редактор даже парные скобки подсветить не может?

Comment: @Visman, notepad++. Я не вижу проблем со скобками, но они судя по всему есть

Comment: @Alexander, в 8 строке открывается 2 скобки, а закрывается только 1.

Comment: @Visman, да, уже исправил, работает, спасибо

Comment: @Visman Да это просто форматирование SO он на первй if подумал что это форматирование и добавил 4-ре пробела, потому как видити ли в списке нельзя отформатировать код.